# Cannot use deploy resource in packer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, chef-infra, packer

We have a chef repo that we normally use with chef-solo and it all works.
When I try to use the same cookbooks in packer to setup an AMI though, I get the error that it cannot find the method `deploy`, aka the deploy resource.

Everything else works fine.
It is downloading chef 14 on ubuntu 16.04.
Anyone had a similliar issue?

**EDIT**: Just found this: https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_deploy_resource.html

*So the deploy resource seems to have been deprecated. I'm going to keep this question here for reference.*

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, this resource was removed (but available in a cookbook) in Chef 14. It was not recommended for use, as it is very complex and generally not required. In most cases, a `git` resource will do what you want.